# empty ListView in simple_list_item_2 mode

Tags: java, android, android-listview

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MemberList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();

item.put("asdf", "asdf");
MemberList.add(item);
item.put("ffff", "ffff");
MemberList.add(item);
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, MemberList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] { "Name", "Level" },
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });

list.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

this is my java code.

but....
there are just two empty blanks

there is no Text in ListView

what should I do ?

Comment: Data is added to the the ArrayList.. if you log it, you see the values in there.

Comment: and you need to new map for each items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
  SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, MemberList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] { "asdf", "ffff" },
    new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
```

You had

```
 item.put("asdf", "asdf");
 item.put("ffff", "ffff");
```

So you need

```
 new String[] { "asdf", "ffff" },
```

Look at the constructor

```
public SimpleAdapter (Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)

Added in API level 1
Constructor

Parameters
context The context where the View associated with this SimpleAdapter is running
data    A List of Maps. Each entry in the List corresponds to one row in the list. The Maps contain the data for each row, and should include all the entries specified in "from"
resource    Resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views for this list item. The layout file should include at least those named views defined in "to"
from    A list of column names that will be added to the Map associated with each item.
to  The views that should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N columns in the from parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayList<String> arr_adt = new ArrayList<String>();

HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MemberList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

item.put("asdf", "asdf");
MemberList.add(item);
item.put("ffff", "ffff");
MemberList.add(item);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MemberList.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.i("MAP", MemberList.toString());

SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this,
        MemberList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        new String[] {"asdf","ffff"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2});

list.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

Hope this helps..:)